# jQuery add dynamic css for specific Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, calendar

I'm having trouble about jQuery add dynamic css for specific Text. This case changes the color of the calendar based on the text of day.

[image]

This is script foreach from Ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('dashboard.index')}}",
    method: "GET",
    content_type: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response.calendar_day_off ?? [], function(key,val){
          $(".day.has-event").text(val.day).css({"background-color": val.basic_color});
        });
    }
});
```

This ini JSON data:

[image]

How can I change the color of this date dynamically. Thank You.

Comment: Hi, can you try like this : `$(".day.has-event[data-date=" + val.startDate + "]").css({"background-color": val.basic_color})` ?